# Remove all files/directories except specified ones in multiple levels

Tags: bash, rm

Is it possible to do the below with one line?

```
shopt -s extglob

rm -r !(folder1|file1|folder2)
rm -r folder2/!(subfolder)
rm -r folder2/subfolder/!(onefile)
```

For example, something like this?

```
rm -r !(folder1|file1|folder2/subfolder/onefile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the (negated) `-path` test of the `find` tool. If the tool supports `-delete` then it's relatively straightforward:

```
find . ! -path ./folder1 ! -path './folder1/*' ! -path ./file1 ! -path ./folder2/subfolder/onefile -delete
```

If `onefile` exists then `subfolder` and `folder2` will be reported in `cannot delete: Directory not empty` errors. This will make them survive but the exit status from `find` will not be `0`.

If your `find` supports `-empty` then you can test directories for being empty before you `-delete` them. In general you don't want to test non-directories for being empty. This complicates the command but allows it to return `0` if everything goes as planned. Like this:

```
find . ! -path ./folder1 \
       ! -path './folder1/*' \
       ! -path ./file1 \
       ! -path ./folder2/subfolder/onefile \
       \( ! -type d -o -empty \) \
       -delete
```

`find` rich enough to support `-delete` and `-empty` will probably support `-regex`. GNU `find` in my Debian can do this:

```
find . ! -regex '\./folder1/*.*\|\./file1\|\./folder2/subfolder/onefile' -delete
```

Notes:

- It's the existence of `onefile` what prevents `find` from deleting `subfolder` or `folder2`. You need more patterns (see down below) or more complicated regex to keep these directories regardless of whether `onefile` is there or not. A variant with more complicated regex:

  ```
  find . ! -regex '\./folder1/*.*\|\./file1\|\./folder2\(/subfolder\(/onefile\)?\)?' -delete
  ```

  As a bonus such improvement fixes the "non-zero exit status" issue.
- `-path` uses glob-like pattern matching notation (`?` matches a single character and `*` matches zero or more characters); `-regex` uses regular expressions (`.` matches a single character and `.*` matches zero or more characters).
- `-path` and `-regex` match against the entire path of a file. To craft patterns that work, you need to know what path `find` will use. Hints:

  - `find` is obliged not to use trailing slash for any path that is not a starting point. This is the reason I used separate `-path` patterns for `./folder1` and files within (`./folder1/*`).
  - On the other hand starting points are used as provided. If the starting point is `.` then all paths will start with `./` except for the path to `.` itself, it will be just `.`. If the starting point is `./` then all paths will start with `./`.
- In my tests `-delete` silently processes `.` without deleting and without error, so there is no need to exclude `.`. On the other hand it throws an error for `./`. I'm not sure how reliable this behavior is. In case of any doubt explicitly exclude `.`, especially if you're after a meaningful exit status.
- [There are few regex types](https://superuser.com/a/1488800/432690). E.g. I could use `-regextype posix-extended` before `! -regex`. The following is **the most compact command I came up with** (not portable though):

  ```
  find . -regextype posix-extended \
       ! -regex './folder1(/.*)?|./file1|./folder2(/subfolder(/onefile)?)?' \
         -delete
  ```

  I intentionally used `.` (wildcard) instead of `\.` (literal dot) for the leading `.`. Since the starting point is `.`, every path will start with `.` for sure, so the wildcard will match nothing else than `.`. Use `\.` if you prefer formal correctness.
- If you want to make sure you don't delete to much, you can "dry run" the command. Change `-delete` to `-print`, you will see what would be deleted. This is the very first command modified this way:

  ```
  find . ! -path ./folder1 ! -path './folder1/*' ! -path ./file1 ! -path ./folder2/subfolder/onefile -print
  ```

  Or negate all preceding tests *as a whole* (which is not the same as negating them separately unless you know what more you need to change; compare [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Negation_of_a_disjunction) to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Negation_of_a_conjunction)) and change `-delete` to `-print` to see what would survive:

  ```
  find . ! \( ! -path ./folder1 ! -path './folder1/*' ! -path ./file1 ! -path ./folder2/subfolder/onefile \) -print
  ```
- Unquoted `./folder1/*` would be a bug: the shell would try to expand `*`.

---

`-path` is [required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) but `-delete`, `-regex` and `-empty` are not. Sometimes `-exec rm {} +` can be used instead of `-delete`, but such `rm` will not remove directories, you need `rmdir`. Yes, `rm -r` can remove directories but then `rm -r ./folder2` will also remove `./folder2/subfolder/onefile` and defy the whole point.

Still our basic approach can be implemented without `-delete` (and somewhat improved):

```
find . -depth \
     ! -path  . \
     ! -path  ./folder1 \
     ! -path './folder1/*' \
     ! -path  ./file1 \
     ! -path  ./folder2 \
     ! -path  ./folder2/subfolder \
     ! -path  ./folder2/subfolder/onefile \
       \( \( ! -type d -exec rm {} + \) -o \( -type d -exec rmdir {} + \) \)
```

By explicitly excluding `./folder2` and `./folder2/subfolder` I made the command return meaningful exit status and keep these directories even if `onefile` doesn't exist.

If you'd like to remove the directories if `onefile` doesn't exist then don't use the extra patterns. Research the `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` option of `rmdir`. This option is not required by POSIX.

I won't say this last command is compact. I like the one with `-regex` better.

Comment: Kudos! That's quite sophisticated. I also like the `regex` method most. I ended up with the following: A) `find . -regextype awk ! -regex "./folder1/.*|./file1|./folder2/subfolder/(fileone|filetwo)" -delete &> /dev/null`, if non-zero exit code is acceptable. B) `find . -type f | grep -Pv "folder1/.*|file1|folder2/subfolder/(fileone|filetwo)" | xargs -d '\n' rm` and then `find . -type d -empty -delete`, which will remove all empty directories; if the slower processing isn't an issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

For such a potentially destructive operation I'd do it carefully, by hand: get a list of all files, with full paths; edit out the files that should stay (`grep  -v`, or with your favorite text editor); check that nothing slipped through; give the list to `rm` (might need to use `xargs(1)` if the list is huge). Be careful with file names containing spaces or other unusual characters!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, regex is still necessary; thus, you have to craft it very carefully.